# Break down WP loop into functions

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to break down a simple foreach loop into two functions: start and end.

**functions.php** :

```
function days_start() {
  $days = [];
  $meals_monday = get_field('monday_meal');
  $meals_tuesday = get_field('tuesday_meal');
  $meals_wednesday = get_field('wednesday_meal');
  $meals_thursday = get_field('thursday_meal');
  $meals_friday = get_field('friday_meal');
  $meals_saturday = get_field('saturday_meal');
  $meals_sunday = get_field('sunday_meal');
  array_push($days, $meals_monday, $meals_tuesday, $meals_wednesday, $meals_thursday, $meals_friday, $meals_saturday, $meals_sunday);

  foreach( $days as $day ):
}

function days_end() {
  endforeach;
}
```

I do this so I can use it multiple times without rewriting it. However, I get this error:

```
"syntax error, unexpected '}'"
```

I think  I must be blind, but I can't see why this would pop up. Or is it not possible to use a foreach function inside a function, without closing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Uh, you always need to close everything.

Comment: I understand, but is it possible to open in one function and close in another?

Comment: Not as far as I know, it would be messy

Comment: Is there another way to regulate this? So to re-use the start and end of a loop?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the need to do it like that. / purpose for it. - So I can hardly help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I removed the foreach statement from the function and did this:

functions.php

```
function days_before_loop() {
  global $days;

  $days = [];
  $meals_monday = get_field('monday_meal');
  $meals_tuesday = get_field('tuesday_meal');
  $meals_wednesday = get_field('wednesday_meal');
  $meals_thursday = get_field('thursday_meal');
  $meals_friday = get_field('friday_meal');
  $meals_saturday = get_field('saturday_meal');
  $meals_sunday = get_field('sunday_meal');
  array_push($days, $meals_monday, $meals_tuesday, $meals_wednesday, $meals_thursday, $meals_friday, $meals_saturday, $meals_sunday);

  return $days;
}
```

then call it like this:

```
days_before_loop();
foreach( $days as $day ):
  // do some stuff
endforeach();
```

Thanks!